# Marker position being updated only for a short period of time in Mapbox GL JS

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have a loop where I am constantly updating the position of a marker:

```
function loop(timestamp) {
   marker._lngLat.lng = clientState.markers[room.sessionId].lng;
   marker._lngLat.lat = clientState.markers[room.sessionId].lat;
   requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
    }
requestAnimationFrame(loop);
```

Strangely, the position is updated only for ~ one second and then stops updating. If the camera position is updated, the position of the marker updates once again for ~ one second and then once again stops updating.

What might be the problem? Thank you in advance for your insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

_lngLat is a private property which has no guarantees, you should use the public method to set location, see the API docs I think it's called setLngLat